# I sold call options that expired ITM. Why were they not exercised?

Tags: options, option-exercise, covered-call-writing, expiration

I sold two covered call positions that expired Aug 9. Both expired ITM.

The 1st one's strike price was $3.00. At expiration, the stock was $3.13 so 13 cents ITM (6 contracts).

The 2nd one's  strike price was $184.50. At expiration,   the stock was $186.49 so almost $2 ITM (1 contract).

Today is Sat, Aug 10, and I see that my short option positions have disappeared but the underlying stock is still there. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possibilities:

- Settlement of the stock hasn't shown up in your account and will do so by Monday morning
- You are the most incredibly lucky guy in the option writing world (not likely)